# :wq! - Resigning as moderator

Tags: discussion, moderation

I just wanted to post this announcement real quick in case people were wondering. As you may have noticed, my name no longer has a diamond next to it. There are a variety of reasons why I'm stepping down, but the main reason is that I'm no longer spending time contributing to the SE network or doing the janitor work. So I feel like continuing to be a moderator is a little bit dishonest. I'm also resigning because of the general direction the SE business is going. I wrote up more of my thoughts [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/18476/31716).

That being said, I'm very grateful for this site. I have enjoyed helping people with vim and learning about it in the process. I think we have succeeded in building up a useful repository of information. I think the site is in [capable hands](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1841/statox), and the flag load is relatively small so I'm sure that the site will be fine.

Although I might not be as active, I'll still be around in chat, so this isn't a goodbye.

`:wq!`

Comment: Thank you for the time you dedicated to our site and our community. It is always a pleasure to interact with you and I'm glad you are not simply leaving the site all together. See you in the chat and the comment sections :)

Comment: Glad you're not leaving entirely! Thanks for all the modding.

Comment: You stole my resignation joke!

Comment: Thanks for everything! Wish you the best.